# When does a role get enabled for a user in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oracle10g

I use ADO.NET from C# 4 in order to set up a test context for a component.

I execute the following SQL as sysdba:

```
new[]
{
    "create user \"{0}\" identified externally default tablespace USER_DATA temporary tablespace TEMP profile DEFAULT"
    .FormatWith( Config.QualifiedUserName ),
    "create role {0}"
    .FormatWith( Config.RoleName ),
    "grant {0} to \"{1}\""
    .FormatWith( Config.RoleName, Config.QualifiedUserName ),
    "insert into doc.application( id, name ) values( {0}, '{1}' )"
    .FormatWith( Config.AppId, Config.AppName ),
    "insert into doc.appl_role( application, role, description ) values( {0}, '{1}', '{2}' )"
    .FormatWith( Config.AppId, Config.RoleName, Config.RoleDescription ),
    "create table {0}.{1} ( ID number primary key, VERSION number, NAME varchar(100) )"
    .FormatWith( Config.TestSchema, Config.TestTable ),
    "insert into {0}.{1} (ID, VERSION, NAME) values ('{2}', '{3}', '{4}')"
    .FormatWith( Config.TestSchema, Config.TestTable, Config.TestRowId, 1, Config.TestRowName ),
    "grant select, insert, update, delete on {0}.{1} to {2}"
    .FormatWith( Config.TestSchema, Config.TestTable, Config.RoleName ),
    "grant create session to \"{0}\""
    .FormatWith( Config.QualifiedUserName )
}
```

and the Config class looks like so:

```
public struct Config
{
    public const Int32 TestRowId = 1;
    public const Int32 AppId = 99999;
    public const String AppName = "OraceUtils";
    public const String RoleName = "ORACLE_UTILS_BASE";
    public static readonly String RoleDescription = "For testing {0}".FormatWith( AppName );
    public static readonly String QualifiedUserName = @"{0}\{1}".FormatWith( Domain, UserName );
    public const String DataSource = "TESTDB";
    public const String Domain = "BI";
    public const String UserName = "ORACLE_TEST_USER";
    public const String UserPassword = [for my eyes only];
    public const String TestSchema = "CI";
    public const String TestTable = "ROLE_PROVIDER_TEST_TABLE";
    public const String TestRowName = "Arne And";
}
```

From what I've read, just granting a role to a user doesn't enable it. However, after executing the SQL above, the user BI\ORACLE_TEST_USER can use the table ROLE_PROVIDER_TEST_TABLE just fine. The role ORACLE_UTILS_BASE also shows in SESSION_ROLES.

If I issue "SET ROLES" afterwards, the aforementioned user can't access the table.

I thought it was the other way around, i.e. that the user wouldn't have access until she issues "SET ROLES ORACLE_UTILS_BASE, [any other roles]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user connects to the DB, all their default roles are enabled. You can change which roles are defaults with the synthax:

```
ALTER USER <user> DEFAULT ROLE <role>
```

`<role>` can be either a role name or the keywords `ALL` or `NONE`

When you grant a role to a user it becomes a default role (i-e the user doesn't have to activate it with `SET ROLE <role>` when they connect).